# Unable to think about a Possible application ofCR equation in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, maxima-minima

I am unable to think about an example given in my class notes related to first course in complex analysis and so I am asking for help here.

> Statement of Question->It has to be shown that $\text{Re}(w)$ admits a overall maximum $z_0$ along $L$, where $L$ is $\text{Re}(z)=x_0$ .

( Above lines I am giving only for reference).

> Please Note that I am only struck in how (1) below implies f(y) = $-\text{Im}(w') (x_0 +i y)$ .

Let $f(y) = \frac{d \text{Re}(w) }{dy}$  $(x_0+i y)$ --(1) and then sir wrote $f(y)= - \text{Im}(w')(x_0 +iy)$.

My attempt ->
If I apply CR equation on (1)(let $f=u+iv$ then if $f$ is analytic, $u_x=v_y$ ,$v_x=- u_y$ ) using $u_y =-v_x$ . So, I am not getting $-\text{Im}(w') (x_0 +i y)$ .

Can someone please tell where I am making mistakes.

Comment: What do you mean by $\text{Re}(w)$ admits a overall maximum $z_0$ along $\text{Re}(z)=x_0$? What is the relation between $z$ and $w$?

Comment: If they are the same thing, shouldn't $\text{Re}(w)$ be simply constant along $L$?

Comment: @Caffeine Line is Re(z) = $x_0$ and it is to be proved that Re(w) admits an overall maximum $z_0$ along L.

Comment: Since on that line $\text{Re}(z)=x_0$, i.e. is constant, I do not see why $\text{Re}(w)=\text{Re}(z)=x_0$ shouldn't hold

Comment: @Caffeinr can you just tell how to get f(y) $= -\text{Im}(w') (x_0 +i y)$ .

Comment: @Caffeine can you please look at statement of question now if you have some time ? I have edited it .

Comment: What is $w'$? You did not define the relations between your variables, making it hard to understand the question

Comment: @Caffeine w' means differentiation of w. I hope question is clear to you now. If not kindly ask where it is unclear, It will also help others.

Comment: Ok, now I understand: $w$ is an (analytic) function of $z$, and $f$ is defined as the derivative of $\text{Re}(w)$ evaluated at $x_0+iy$. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$w(z)=u(z)+iv(z)\\
u(z)=\text{Re}(w);\ v(z)=\text{Im}(w)\\
f=\partial_y \text{Re}(w)_{|x_0+iy}=\partial_y u=^*-\partial_x v=-\partial_x\text{Im}(w)_{|x_0+iy}\\
$$

*: Cauchy-Riemann equations